# SQLAgent job powershell step fails with "login failed for <DOMAIN>\<COMPUTER>$"

Tags: sql-server, powershell, authentication, powershell-2.0

I am using a SQL Server job to get some wmiobject details into a table. 
This code runs with default installation, but fails when I execute it on a named instance. So far I have seen only one difference in connection, for the named instance, SQL Agent is using with a user name which has "$" as part of the name (i.e. `NT Service\SQLAgent$instance`)

Is there anyway  I can overcome this? Changing the agent account is not an option as most of the servers run with this account and my code needs to work with all accounts.

```
    $conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=$SqlSvr;Initial Catalog=$Database; Integrated Security=SSPI") 

$conn.Open()
```

> Executed as user: NT Service\SQLAgent$instance.  A job step received
>   an error at line 21 in a PowerShell script. The corresponding line is
>   '    $conn.Open()  '... The error information returned by PowerShell
>   is: 'Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "Login failed for
>   user '(DOMAIN)(COMPUTER)$'."  '.  Process Exit Code -1.

I tried with "identity impersonate =true" but it didn't accept the command.

Any ideas?

Comment: You say this is a SQL Agent Job. Is it executing SQL PowerShell or Operating System(CmdExec)? Why not create a Proxy account and use it in the Job\Step\RunAs?

Answer (score 0):

Ether use ' instead of " or use the escape Char ` or use char(36)

```
"blahblah`$blahblah"

'blahblah$blahblah'

"blahblah$([char](36))blahblah"
```

Comment: The issue is,  it is not visible in code. It is sending the account details internally.

Comment: This issue is resolved.  The problem was with $SqlSvr.  For different reason,  I was sending a value through another variable, but due to a bug it it took it as a literal string.

Comment: What "bug" are you referring to #user3245595?